# BIOBERT Pre-trained Word Embeddings into CNN using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, bert-language-model

I have a textual dataset of 15000 rows and a label for each row. since my dataset is in the clinical domain, I want to use BIOBERT pre-trained word embeddings on the textual data using tensorflow and then use it as an input to a CNN network for prediction. Can anyone please show me how to implement this on any textual field using python and tensorflow.